# Unable to schedule unique work on WorkManager

Tags: android, job-scheduling, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I am using work manager to schedule unique work. While it works perfectly on most of the phones, it is failing to schedule on specific Mi Max device.
This is the code snippet

```
Constraints myConstraints = new Constraints.Builder()
        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
        .build();
OneTimeWorkRequest myWork =
         new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class)
                 .setInitialDelay(transmissionFreq, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                 .setConstraints(myConstraints)
                 .addTag("JobTag")
                 .build();
WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniqueWork("JobTag", ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, myWork);
```

From logcat I can find below logs.

```
2019-01-31 20:52:00.255 1286-1308/com.inmobi.data.test D/WM-Processor: Processor cancelling 59ee78d1-8a8b-4d66-8392-40b634553840
2019-01-31 20:52:00.256 1286-1308/com.inmobi.data.test D/WM-Processor: WorkerWrapper could not be found for 59ee78d1-8a8b-4d66-8392-40b634553840
2019-01-31 20:52:00.259 1286-1308/com.inmobi.data.test D/WM-GreedyScheduler: Cancelling work ID 59ee78d1-8a8b-4d66-8392-40b634553840
2019-01-31 20:52:00.277 1286-1308/com.inmobi.data.test D/WM-PackageManagerHelper: androidx.work.impl.background.systemalarm.RescheduleReceiver enabled
2019-01-31 20:52:00.294 1286-1308/com.inmobi.data.test D/WM-SystemJobScheduler: Scheduling work ID 115c9814-d1f7-488c-913e-2b5af2bf1972 Job ID 81
2019-01-31 20:52:00.308 1286-1308/com.inmobi.data.test D/WM-Processor: Processor stopping 59ee78d1-8a8b-4d66-8392-40b634553840
2019-01-31 20:52:00.309 1286-1308/com.inmobi.data.test D/WM-Processor: WorkerWrapper could not be found for 59ee78d1-8a8b-4d66-8392-40b634553840
2019-01-31 20:52:00.309 1286-1308/com.inmobi.data.test D/WM-StopWorkRunnable: StopWorkRunnable for 59ee78d1-8a8b-4d66-8392-40b634553840; Processor.stopWork = false
```

I am not sure what does it mean by **WorkerWrapper could not be found**. Because it is able to schedule the work once in while, but failing most of the other time.

Also apart from reason, can anyone point any workaround or fix for this issue.

More info on the project

- Min SDK version: 17
- Compile SDK version: 28
- Target SDK version: 28
- WorkManager version: 1.0.0-beta03
- Device: Mi Max
- Device Android
  version: 7.0

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was not with the work manager. The issue was happening because the device was having battery saver turned on. Which won't allow any background processing if the app is not in the foreground.

Comment: @Zookey turn-off battery saver on the testing device

Comment: What about the real-life usage when a user might have battery saver on?